# DynamoDb global tables atomic counters region-concurent write behaviour

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We have dynamodb global table in 2 regions. The table contains info like website clicks with key **user** and one more column **total_user_clicks**, which in turn is a number value. To increment this value we use the atomic counter dynamodb feature.

Let's consider the next situation. At a single moment of time, we send two increment updates for a single key from two different regions. My question is: What would be the final result? Do we have guaranteed, that it will be +2 eventually? Or, it can be +1 or +2, depending on replication circumstances?

As I understand, if we replicate the db log, instead of raw rows, we have guaranteed to have +2 eventually. But I can't find any confirmation in official docs.

Answer (score 0):

If the `ADD` requests are from different region, it can be both +1 or +2.

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/V2globaltables_HowItWorks.html), requests can cause conflict if they update the same item in different region while replication.

And even if the request could be reconciled without conflicts (i.e. add operations or update different paths on the same key), it always raises conflict and overwrites to the last writer. So the former request will be ignored.

Therefore, 3 possible cases for 2 requests from different regions.

1. Result is +1, conflicts, request 1 wins.
2. Result is +1, conflicts, request 2 wins.
3. Result is +2, no conflicts, both requests does not overlap replication time.